# Set Authorization token in rails4 header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I cab able to handle authentication, passing params[:auth_token] through URL and get results,

like this, `/event_tasks?auth_token=vDJLVv66BBg-DWWKMrF6`

But instead of this i wanted to set `auth_token` as header and proceed,

ex: header as `"Authorization: Token auth_token=vDJLVv66BBg-DWWKMrF6"`
and URL as `/event_tasks`

How to achieve this in Rails4

Answer (score 0):

For OAuth2.0, according to the specification the server should support.

Authorization: Bearer vDJLVv66Bg-DWWKMrF6

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers and CGI variables can be set directly on the @request instance variable:

```
@request.headers["Authorization"] = "Token token=vDJLVv66BBg-DWWKMrF6"
get :index # simulate the request with custom header
```

See the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#setting-headers-and-cgi-variables